# Equivalent of CSS "float:left;" for images

Tags: graphics, floats, formatting

What I am try here is have the image on the left side and it should be surrounded by text on the right and bottom side.

For example how can below `image_3.png` float to left?

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{./images/image_3.png}
\lipsum[1]    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Depending on your distribution, you can either look at the [`wrapfig` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) or the [`picins` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/picins).

Comment: If you want to use URLs in your text, use the [`url` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) to provide you with a consistent format: `\url{http://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pgf.html}`

Comment: @Werner thanks! oh, the url screw up is totally was my fault. I just put a text there to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Werner mentions you can use [the `wrapfig` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Don't use [demo] option in your real example
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{./images/image_3.png}
    \caption{Image3.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! one problem I am having is to setting the right and bottom margins. I can control bottom margin with \vspace but how I can control the right one or left?

Comment: Does adjust the width `{0.6\textwidth}` not do what you want?

Answer (score 6):

You can insert the image using [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig), and adjust the left and right margins through modification of `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{wrapfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig
\usepackage{url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/url
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\addtolength{\leftskip}{5em} \addtolength{\rightskip}{2em}% Adjust margins

% \begin{wrapfigure}[<number of narrow lines>]{<placement>}[<overhang>]{<width>} <stuff> \end{wrapfigure}
\begin{wrapfigure}[6]{l}{5em}
  \rule{5em}{4\baselineskip}% place your image here using \includegraphics
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent You can draw graphics directly with TeX commands using the \verb!tikz! package: 
\url{http://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pgf.html} It comes 
with very good documentation with many examples.
You can draw graphics directly with TeX commands using the \verb!tikz! package: 
\url{http://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pgf.html} It comes 
with very good documentation with many examples.

\addtolength{\leftskip}{-5em} \addtolength{\rightskip}{-2em}% Restore margins

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}​
```

If you're after modifying the margins of the actual image that you included, you need to modify the parameters of the `wrapfigure` environment:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[<number of narrow lines>]{<placement>}[<overhang>]{<width>}
  <stuff>
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Increasing `<number of narrow lines>` will push the bottom further down, while increasing  `<width>` will push the right margin further in.

For completeness, I've included [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) for dummy text as well as [`url`](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) since you had an URL in your MWE. [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) (with the package option `showframe`) was also included to show the margin adjustment with respect to the other document elements.