# Equivalent of <div style="float:right"></div>?

Tags: graphics, floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of CSS “float:left;” for images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32188/equivalent-of-css-floatleft-for-images)

I come from an HTML/CSS background, and would like to know the LaTeX equivalent of the following HTML snippet:

```
<div style="float:right">(i put an image here, might be from \includegraphics{..} or \input{..})</div>
```

In other words, how do I make an image float on the right side of the text, and have the text properly wrap around it?

In my case, the text consists of normal text and enumerations.